# What is the difference between hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz and hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz files

Tags: hadoop

When i am installing hadoop in my machine i find out there are two stable files preset in apache hadoop website. First one is hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz and second one is hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz. So basically what is the difference of two files. My guess is hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz file is used as source code of hadoop and hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz is contains all HDFS application.

Comment: hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz contains the source code , hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz is the binary tar ball

Comment: So what is the basic difference of these two files. I think both files can be use to setup hadoop in single, pseudo and multi node mode. So why we are use hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz instead of hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz.

Comment: The difference is, you will need to build the code from the source tar ball before you can use them. Where as the binary distribution can be used right  after u extract it.

Answer (score 1):

As the name of the file in them self suggest:

> hadoop-1.2.1.bin.tar.gz -- This contains the Binary or executables (In later releases of hadoop, this is not included  for download and need to be built locally using maven)
>
> hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz -- This contains your src code which is distributed for your reference.

The latest stable release is 2.5.2, it is highly recommended to use the latest release.

Comment: You may accept the answer, if it answers your question.